# Some apps tray icons shown only in the compiz widgets layer

Tags: 11.10, notification-area, cairo-dock, widgets

I'm noticing that some apps tray icons (gnome-rdp, UPS Status, blueproximity) are missing from the tray notification area but are shown below the bar when you F9 to the compiz widgets layer.

Any way to bring'en back to the correct place?

I'm running a cairo-dock gnome session and a cairo-dock theme named oneiric-panel. Cairo-dock's "notification area" and "old notification area" modules are bound to Cairo-dock0s upper dock. When I accidentally pressed F9 I discovered my missing tray icons below Cairo-dock's upper dock...

Comment: What does this have to do with Cairo-dock? Are you using the system tray of Cairo-dock or something?

Comment: I'm running a cairo-dock gnome session and a cairo-dock theme named oneiric-panel. Cairo-dock's "notification area" and "old notification area" modules are bound to Cairo-dock0s upper dock. When I accidentally pressed F9 I discovered my missing tray icons below Cairo-dock's upper dock...

Comment: Why didn't you make that clear in your question???

Comment: I think the title of my question contained the reference to the gnome cairo-dock session, but was edited by a moderator for shortening the rather long sentence. Besides, cairo-dock was involved in the discovery of the missing icons (you can use it to reproduce the staging) but I don't think it is directly causing the icons to go to the widgets layer of compiz, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

*(comment to answer by OP)*

I'm running a cairo-dock gnome session and a cairo-dock theme named oneiric-panel. Cairo-dock's "notification area" and "old notification area" modules are bound to Cairo-dock0s upper dock. When I accidentally pressed F9 I discovered my missing tray icons below Cairo-dock's upper dock... – ivanxx Dec 10 '11 at 20:48